# Code explain Python Class keyword argparse with Namespace

Tags: python

I have given a task to solve and understand Python OOP concept.
In following code I did not understand what is the purpose of this following line?

```
user.args = argparse.Namespace(**data)
```

And how do I access keyword arguments in **User** class method *displayUser*, because object of **User** class is already created before passing the argument. This is what I thought.

Can anyone explain the following code?

```
import argparse 


class User(object):
   
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def displayUser(self):
        pass



if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = {
        "val_1": "John",
        "val_2": "Doe",
    }

    user = User()
    user.args = argparse.Namespace(**data)
```

Comment: Currently the line does not seem to have any purpose, because `user.args` is not used anywhere. `displayUser` has no keyword arguments, so it's unclear to me how you want to access any.

Comment: This is a very weird usage of argparse, usually you would use namespaces through the argument to parse_args.
To answer your question: you can access values with `user.args.val_1` but I don't think this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can make a guess what you want to do: In `displayUser`, write something like `print(self.args.val_1)`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 So, in that case, we don't need to pass arguments through an object? When we use ```argparse.Namespace()```

Comment: You should not normally use `argparse.Namespace` at all. It just exists as a container for command line arguments returned by `argparse`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
def displayUser(self):
    print(f"Firstname: {self.args.val_1}, last name: {self.args.val_2}")
```

You can directly access the val_1 and val_2 from the Namespace object that you set to `user.args`. In python you can set fields of an object despite them not being defined in the constructor, whether this is a nice approach is a totally different question (it is not, imho).

Comment: So, in that case, we don't need to pass arguments through an object? When we use ```argparse.Namespace()```

Comment: @trojanatwar I don't exactly know what you mean with "pass arguments through an object". But with the argparse.Namespace you are basically transforming the dictionary into a structured "type" where you can access the values to the keys the same as you would with a class. (Think of a struct in c++, or a class without methods).
I actually don't like this usage here very much though. Better let the first and last name be given to the constructor and explicitly save it in there.